# remote pyspark shell and spark-submit error java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: METASTORE_CLIENT_SOCKET_LIFETIME

Tags: java, python, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

we are executing pyspark and spark-submit to kerberized CDH 5.15v from remote airflow docker container not managed by CDH CM node, e.g. airflow container is not in CDH env.
Versions of hive, spark and java are the same as on CDH. There is a valid kerberos ticket before executing spark-submit or pyspark.

Python script:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, functions as F
spark = SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport().appName('appName').getOrCreate()
sa_df=spark.sql("SELECT * FROM lnz_ch.lnz_cfg_codebook")
```

Error is:

```
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.3.0
      /_/

Using Python version 3.6.12 (default, Oct 13 2020 21:45:01)
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
>>> from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, functions as F
>>> spark = SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport().appName('appName').getOrCreate()
>>> sa_df=spark.sql("SELECT * FROM lnz_ch.lnz_cfg_codebook")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/var/lib/airflow/spark/spark-2.3.0-bin-without-hadoop/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 708, in sql
    return DataFrame(self._jsparkSession.sql(sqlQuery), self._wrapped)
  File "/var/lib/airflow/spark/spark-2.3.0-bin-without-hadoop/python/lib/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1160, in __call__
  File "/var/lib/airflow/spark/spark-2.3.0-bin-without-hadoop/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/var/lib/airflow/spark/spark-2.3.0-bin-without-hadoop/python/lib/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 320, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o24.sql.
: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: METASTORE_CLIENT_SOCKET_LIFETIME
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.formatTimeVarsForHiveClient(HiveUtils.scala:195)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:286)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client$lzycompute(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:65)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply$mcZ$sp(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:195)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:195)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:195)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:97)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.databaseExists(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:194)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SharedState.scala:114)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog(SharedState.scala:102)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.externalCatalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:39)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.catalog$lzycompute(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:54)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.catalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder$$anon$1.<init>(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:69)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.analyzer(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:69)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.BaseSessionStateBuilder$$anonfun$build$2.apply(BaseSessionStateBuilder.scala:293)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.BaseSessionStateBuilder$$anonfun$build$2.apply(BaseSessionStateBuilder.scala:293)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionState.analyzer$lzycompute(SessionState.scala:79)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionState.analyzer(SessionState.scala:79)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:55)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:74)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:638)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Same error is retured from yarn when executing spark-submit.

Details:

- beeline works from container

Comment: You should probably talk to Cloudera's support. It looks like a deployment issue, not a programming issue. Beeline is irrelevant, because it probably accesses Hive rather than Spark with Hive support. It seems you have incompatible classes in your classpath somewhere.

Comment: Details of our solution can be found here:
https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/remote-pyspark-shell-and-spark-submit-error-java-lang/td-p/309553